# write a shell script to find all vowels present in a file and print the corresponding words

Tags: shell, operating-system, sh

I am trying to find out the solution but don't know from where to start can you suggest some answer or solution of this question that would be really helpful

Comment: what is your definition of "words"?

Answer (score 0):

Your vowels words are including the character in `[aeiou]` ?

If yes, try this:

`grep -ioE '\w*[aeiou]\w*' file_name`

and if you want to ignore-case and get unique words, you can add this:

`| tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort | uniq`